# FastAPI "Not authenticated" despite being authenticated in docs

Tags: authentication, fastapi

This is my code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm

app = FastAPI()

Oauth_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer("token")

@app.post("/token")
async def token(token: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    
    return {'access_token': 'someToken',}

@app.get('/', dependencies=[Depends(Oauth_scheme)])
async def root():
    return {'data': 'someData',}
```

If run it in swagger, do authentication, then I am able to run get route and I get data out. But if I do hit my browser with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` I get out:

```
detail  "Not authenticated"
```

Why is this happening? And how I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you are not checking if the "token" that is coming with request is correct or not.
But, since you have protected your API with OAuth Token, you need to send a token as a header to `/` endpoint.

In order to do that, you can use any Client like Postman, Python Requests, cURL etc.

I am attaching here an implementation of cURL, but you can easily convert this to postman or any other Client.

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer someToken'
```

Here, someToken can be any random string (because you are not checking whether the token is correct or not).